# Understanding Hash Lock Atomic Swaps

Tags: hash, cryptography, hash-algorithm

I have trouble understanding how exactly atomic swaps take place in HTLCs. Let's take the generic example:

Alice wants to trade 1 BTC with Bob in exchange for 15 ETH.

Alice creates a contract where she deposits the 1 BTC that unlocks with a PK / passcode. She creates a hash of this address? or of this transaction?

This hash is then sent to Bob who can verify that the funds are in place. He then sends his 15 ETH to the address of the hash.

Alice unlocks Bob's funds using the passcode. And then Bob can observe this and use the same passcode to unlock the swapped funds.

**If the passcode is the same can't Alice be super fast and just get both sets of funds?**

I'm guessing these some cryptographic trickery at play that makes Alice and Bob's passcodes different but I can't find this explained anywhere. I'm interested to learn how this really works.

Any information would be greatly appreciated